# javascript plotting realtime

Tags: javascript, real-time, plot

I need realtime plotting in javascript, and I came across this:

http://nme.pl/en/2011/01/real-time-graph-using-javascript

This is close to what i want. Now that my javascript understanding is limited, can any guru point me where from this canvas is getting data? Is it taking from any online url? What is that google analytics url about?

Comment: You could also try Flot : http://code.google.com/p/flot/ The link you showed gets it data from a random number generator `Rotator`

Answer (score 1):

The post is old but came up when googling so I thought I'd post some links to more modern solutions.

Rickshaw is getting some good reviews - https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw

Smoothie is also getting some good reviews and I've seen it in action - https://github.com/joewalnes/smoothie

HTH

Answer (score 0):

That particular example is getting data from a JavaScript function that generates "random" data. Code is:

```
// rotating across pseudo-random values array
var Rotator = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.data = [
        16,23,41,38,45,31,29,22,27,22,25,29,32,45,88,30,
        26,22,45,23,36,48,99,22,32,26,22,27,5,0,0,3,15
    ];
    self.index = 0;
    self.single = function() {
        self.index += 1;
        if (self.index > self.data.length) {
            self.index = 1;
        }
        return self.data[self.index-1];
    };
    self.many = function(length) {
        var results = [];
        for (var i=0;i<length;i++) {
            results.push(self.single());
        }
        return results;
    };
};
```

As mentioned in comments, you can look at Flor or Ext-JS (Sencha).

Comment: ok, i got this for fusion, but it seems using some flash / flex, i need pure JS. http://www.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Demos/RealTimeJS/Index.html

Comment: Have you looked at Flot / Sencha ?